# How to Handle Different Expect Messages?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, expect

Going to need help from folks who have experience writing expect script.  I am unable to find a correct solution to handle multiple type of messages returned in expect script.  I am trying to test 2 scenarios where final message returned may have two different type of response.  In addition to handling that response, there is no expectation to send any response for final echo message. how do I achieve this ?

```
test_script.sh
---------------
#!/bin/bash

echo "Session Name ?"
read $REPLY
echo "First Name   ?"
read $REPLY
echo "Last Name    ?"
read $REPLY
echo "Op#          ?"
read $REPLY
echo "Password     ?"
read $REPLY
echo "Password again?"
read $REPLY
echo "Session Name: RajP"
echo "First Name  : Raj"
echo "Last Name   : P"
echo "OP#         : Arch"
echo "Continue? (y|n)"
read $REPLY
echo "row count = 1"

test_script2.sh
---------------
#!/bin/bash

echo "Session Name ?"
read $REPLY
echo "First Name   ?"
read $REPLY
echo "Last Name    ?"
read $REPLY
echo "Op#          ?"
read $REPLY
echo "Password     ?"
read $REPLY
echo "Password again?"
read $REPLY
echo "Session Name: RajP"
echo "First Name  : Raj"
echo "Last Name   : P"
echo "OP#         : Arch"
echo "Continue? (y|n)"
read $REPLY
echo "You already have a ses_data record for OP_NBR=Arch"

expect_test_script.sh
---------------------
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
spawn ./test_script.sh
expect "Session Name ?\r"
send "RajP\r"
expect "First Name   ?\r"
send "Raj\r"
expect "Last Name    ?\r"
send "P\r"
expect "Op#          ?\r"
send "Arch\r"
expect "Password     ?\r"
send "Pass123\r"
expect "Password again?\r"
send "Pass123\r"
expect "Session Name: RajP\r"
expect "First Name  : Raj\r"
expect "Last Name   : P\r"
expect "OP#         : Arch\r"
expect "Continue? (y|n)\r"
send "y\r"
expect {
        "You already have a ses_data record for OP_NBR=Arch"{exp_continue}
        "row count = 1"{exp_continue}
       }
expect eof

My expect script is trying to test 2 different shell scripts : test_script.sh  and test_script2.sh ... 
It fails with this message 

expect: spawn id exp7 not open
    while executing
"expect eof"
    (file "./expect_test_script.sh" line 26)
```

**How do I code my expect script so it can handle last Echo of both test scripts ( test_script.sh and test_script2.s )?**

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind... It was error in expect script.   This fixed it.

```
expect {
        "You already have a ses_data record for OP_NBR=Arch" {}
        "row count = 1" {}
       }
expect eof
```